# Является ли переменная объектом в ООП?

Tags: c#, c++, ооп, терминология

Я, начинающий программист на C#, спорю сейчас с программистом на C++. Он утверждает, что в ООП переменная - это не объект, во всяком случае в C++. Я утверждаю, что переменная - это в корне тоже объект определенного типа в любом объктно-ориентированном языке. Кто из нас прав? Хотелось бы услышать мнение профессионалов.

Comment: Плюс: вопрос интересный, в процессе изучения материала узнал много нового.

Comment: ты прав-объект

Comment: Столько мнений и ответов. И каждый по своему прав. Трудно выбрать правильный ответ...

Comment: Можно же утверждать, что переменная — это контейнер объекта?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

В С это не так — там просто нет понятия "объект". =)

---

Объект отличается от не объекта тем, что он имеет сложное и активное внутреннее устройство.

Не объект всего лишь является отображением участка памяти. Будь то просто число, указатель, некий обычный массив или структура. Действия над ними — просто оперирование данными в памяти. Взял, изменил, положил обратно. Вне зависимости от содержимого участка памяти. И переменная эта никаких возмущений в эти действия не вносит.

Объект — это тоже отображение участка памяти. Но только доступ к нему осуществляется уже не напрямую, а через посредников — через свойства, методы класса и т.д. То есть в любом случае происходит вызов некоторой процедуры, реализующей метод класса, которой передаются указатель на объект и аргументы (или как-то похоже). Что в этой процедуре произойдёт — одному разработчику известно. Ну и документации.

Моё мнение — в компилируемом и статически типизируемом языке **обычно** (но вовсе не обязательно) простые переменные не являются объектами.

В C# практически любая переменная — объект (как справедливо заметили, за исключением указателей). Ввиду того, что типы `int`, `string`, `char` и все иные — это, так сказать, синонимы соответствующих классов: `System.Int32`, `System.String`, `System.Char`.
В С++ — нет.

А в динамически типизируемом языке у каждой переменной, как минимум, есть скрытые свойства - тип, например. И действия совершаются различные в зависимости от содержимого оного свойства. И оператор + числа сложит, строки склеит и т.д.

Comment: так C++ - это ОПП или не совсем ООП или совсем не ООП?

Comment: <pre>
"Я придумал термин "объектно-ориентированный",
и вот что я вам скажу, я не имел ввиду С++." 
-- Алан Кей, OOPSLA '97
</pre>

Comment: С++ &mdash; это расширение языка Си, добавляющее некоторые возможности которые свойсвенные ОО языкам.

Comment: Ну, С++ - ООП, т.к. имеет все свойства ООП языка. То есть возможность реализовать __средствами языка__ инкапсуляцию, наследование и полиморфизм. Но он же имеет базовые типы, к которым это не применимо. Если следовать самому строгому определению ООП, то да С++ имеет ООП возможности, но полностью таким языком не является.

Comment: Ура, цитаты пошли. Можно добавить?
Object-oriented programming generates a lot of what looks like work. Back in the days of fanfold, there was a type of programmer who would only put five or ten lines of code on a page, preceded by twenty lines of elaborately formatted comments. Object-oriented programming is like crack for these people: it lets you incorporate all this scaffolding right into 
your source code. (c) Paul Graham

Comment: Я так и не понял, как форматировать комментарии ><

Comment: В комментах работает &lt;pre&gt;. Как я понял, это временная мера, потом будет введена разметка.

Comment: >Ну, С++ - ООП, т.к. имеет все свойства ООП языка.

 А я читал где-то, что это недоООП. Не могу вспомнить где читал, и какие аргументы там приводились, но могу привести например то, что в нём нет большинства модных возможностей современных ООП языков (например, свойств). Ещё, в нём плохо реализуется инкапсуляция: невозможно скрыть "кишки" класса, даже поместив его в отдельную библиотеку. Через заголовочный файл видно, какие данные-члены он имеет. Из-за этого приходится извращаться, придумывая pimpl и другие техники.

Answer (score 15):

> Он утверждает, что в ООП переменная - это не объект, во всяком случае в C.

В Си нету объектов, Си является процедурным языком. Если имели ввиду C++, то ответ тот же — значение переменной не обязательно является объектом.

> Я утверждаю, что переменная - это в корне тоже объект определенного типа в любом объектно-ориентированном языке.

Я бы с вами с удовольствием согласился, но, к сожалению, C++ считают объектно-ориентированным языком, поэтому ответ нет.

В C++ это так из-за того что он основан на Си и обязан играть по его правилам.

Во многих объектно-ориентированных языках это так. (Python, Ruby, Smalltalk). В Java также как и в C++ базовые типы (`int`) не являются объектами, но в случае Java для них есть объекты-аналоги(`Integer`).

Answer (score 12):

Ответ, выбранный лучшим, неверный. На самом деле, в нем попытались ответить на другой вопрос: являются ли **значения**, которые содержат переменные, ссылками на объекты, или примитивами. Оригинальный же вопрос был задан относительно переменных - **слотов**, временно или постоянно существующих в некоторых областях памяти: куче, стеке, регистрах CPU. Переменная является объектом тогда и только тогда, когда язык предоставляет программисту **объектный интерфейс**, состоящий из операций по управлению слотом этой переменной: создание нового слота, помещение значения в слот, удаление слота, извлечение текущего значения из слота, и т.д. Ни один из известных мне объектно-ориентированных языков программирования не предоставляет в явной форме такого объектного интерфейса для своих переменных. В этих языках операции создания слота (переменной), извлечения текущего значения и размещения нового реализуются специальными синтаксическими конструкциями языка, а не вызовом методов, как это могло бы быть:

```
SomeObject x; // Создание переменной x.
              // Сравните с: Environment.getCurrent().createVariable("x")
x = 20;       // Помещение значения в переменную.
              // Сравните с: Environment.getCurrent().lookupVariable("x").assign(20)
x;            // Извлечение значения переменной.
              // Сравните с: Environment.getCurrent().lookupVariable("x").getValue()
```

А операция удаления слота и вовсе не доступна в явном виде программисту, как могла бы быть:

```
// Environment.getCurrent().free("x")
```

Чтобы лучше понять, как бы выглядела работа с переменными, будь они объектами, рассмотрим похожую проблему. Зададимся вопросом: *а являются ли функции (или методы) объектами*? Для Java/C#/C++ ответ отрицательный (если анонимные функции в C# имеют объектный интерфейс, просьба меня поправить). Но, скажем, в языке Scala, функции (и методы) и правда являются объектами, иными словами, они имеют **объектные интерфейсы**. К примеру, создадим новую функцию для двух аргументов, которую положим в переменную sum:

```
scala> val sum = (x: Int, y: Int) => x + y
sum: (Int, Int) => Int = <function2>
```

Созданная функция - объект, который является экземпляром некоторого класса:

```
scala> sum.getClass
res5: java.lang.Class[_ <: (Int, Int) => Int] = class $anonfun$1
```

Вызвать (применить) функцию можно традиционным способом:

```
scala> sum(5,6)
res6: Int = 11
```

А можно и с помощью **объектного интерфейса**:

```
scala> sum.apply(5,6)
res7: Int = 11
```

Создадим еще одну функцию, на этот раз с помощью явного создания объекта на основе интерфейса *Function2*, представляющего функции для двух аргументов:

```
scala> val mul = new Function2[Int,Int, Int] { def apply(x: Int, y: Int) = x * y }
mul: java.lang.Object with (Int, Int) => Int = <function2>
```

Полученная функция также является обычным объектом с методом apply:

```
scala> mul.apply(5,9)
res8: Int = 45
```

Еще один полезный метод, который предоставляет объектный интерфейс для функций - это операция карирования функции, которая позволяет вытворять такие вещи:

```
scala> val sum2 = sum.curried
sum2: Int => Int => Int = <function1>

scala> val inc = sum2(1)
inc: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> List(inc(7), inc(20), inc(35))
res10: List[Int] = List(8, 21, 36)

scala> val dec = sum2(-1)
dec: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> List(dec(7), dec(20), dec(35))
res11: List[Int] = List(6, 19, 34)
```

По аналогии, будь наши переменные объектами, мы бы могли обращаться к ним как к обычным объектам, вызывая их методы, как в случае с функциями. Но языки программирования не предоставляют такой возможности. Переменные в них НЕ являются объектами. В отличие от **значений** этих переменных. Путать эти два понятия не стоит.

Answer (score 10):

Почему я не могу комментировать? :)

Ну да ладно. Тут выше написали, что

> Си шарп тоже ОО язык от мозга до
> костей. Там абсолютно все являются
> объектами. Отец и мать там всему -
> Object

Так вот это жуткий-жуткий бред. В C# есть сущности, не неследуемые от Object. Это указатели, интерфейсы, параметры типов в дженериках.

Comment: Комментировать, вроде, можно тока с 50 очков .-. Уже скоро =)

Comment: Итого - ни С++, ни C# полностью ОО языками не являются :-) И даже Java тоже. Т.к. в ней я не нашел соответствия как в C# между базовыми типами и соответствующими классами типа System.Int32.

Comment: Видимо так =D Впрочем, я не считаю это плохим =)

Comment: @gecube, а как же autoboxing? ) Но по факту - да, не является.

Comment: Справедливости ради, в C# интерфейсы таки наследуют от `System.Object`. И параметры типов (фактические, но не формальные) - тоже.

Answer (score 7):

Столь долгое обсуждение навело на мысль: а извините, пожалуйста, а где вы видели ООП язык?? ООП не более чем подход, но никак уж не язык, тогда есть АОП язык что ли? Когда вы реализуете ООП на каком-либо языке, это не значит, что это язык ООП. Если подход ООП, там объекты, но если ООП в решении кураг задач и нафиг не надо, тогда какие объекты? Умение определять, где ООП надо, а где нет, тоже, кстати, дело не из простых.

Comment: Smalltalk является объектно ориентированным языком. И это не просто подход, он является ОО языком от мозга до костей.

Comment: так все же это именно ОО язык или язык для ОО ?

Comment: Это именно ОО-язык. Язык в котором всё -- объекты. В Smalltalk объекты общаются посредством посылки друг-другу сообщений. В Smalltalk даже сообщения, являются объектами у которых есть метод sendTo. Классы тоже являются объектами, у которых есть метод subclass.<pre></pre>

При этом Smalltalk является первым языком ОО-языком программирования, с которого все взяли пример.

Comment: Си шарп тоже ОО язык от мозга до костей. Там абсолютно все являются объектами. Отец и мать там всему Object

Comment: Чаще основоположником ОО программирования называют язык simula-67 (из потомков алгола-60)

Answer (score 6):

> Я утверждаю, что переменная - это в корне тоже объект определенного типа в любом объктно-ориентированном языке

Я склонен думать именно так. Просто типы объектов могут быть встроенные в язык (long int, например), а могут быть пользовательскими (собственно, классы, например).

См. еще Чем отличается экземпляр класса от объекта класса?>тут

Отмечу, что в C/C++ объект - все, что имеет адрес в памяти. Т.е. является lvalue.
Переменные ссылочного типа (напр., &int) - объектами по сути не являются!?!?

PS: с каждым разом все убеждаюсь в мнении, что C++ язык непростой, а представляющий из себя мешанину различных концепций...

Comment: у `long int` есть методы?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, по ссылке <<См. еще тут>> вообще ничего не понятно. Хотелось бы услышать мнения других, а если есть не просто мнение, а факт... В книгах по шарпу это утверждение есть, а как во всех остальных языках? ООП - это объектно-ориентированное программирование. Значит из этого определения можно сказать, что всё во всех языках ООП являются объектами? Этот вопрос вроде и не столь важен для программиста, но что то меня он зацепил...

Comment: >> у `long int` есть методы?
на шарпе есть. На шарпе во всем есть минимум 4 метода

Comment: А в C++ нет.

Comment: В С# все встроенные типы int, long - псевдонимы соответствующих классов из пространства имён System. Видимо, чтобы удобнее было и привычно - как в С++.

Comment: объект - это и есть переменная. См. Страуструпа.
К тому же у любого встроенного типа есть конструктор. О, да.

Comment: Это всего лишь один из вариантов инициализации переменной. Посмотрите стандарт: http://www.kuzbass.ru/docs/isocpp/decl.html пункт 8.5 - Initializers [dcl.init].

Компилятор это подтверждает - машинный код при такой инициализации и при обычной "int i = 1;" ничем не отличается (специально проверил).

Не критично, но, как минимум, обычные числовые переменные - не объекты. При компиляции они могут отобразиться даже не в память, а всего лишь в один регистр.

Comment: Второе выражение - это то же самое, только чуть посложнее. Объявляется указатель на число, после чего для него выделяется где-то память. И инициализируется так же, как если бы её объявили статически. По сути тут добавился только динамический указатель=)

Но я соглашусь - это вопрос терминологии.

Comment: С точки зрения ООП я почитаю объектами только экземпляры классов. С точки зрения более общей - просто некоторого языка - объектами можно назвать все данные, которыми оперирует программа, то есть то, что находится в оперативной и иной изменяемой в ходе выполнения программы памяти и может поменять своё значение. (Потому и плюс от меня - ответ не неправильный, а с иной стороны)

Но вот что не ня - под это определение попадают переменные из всех языков, даже регистры процессора в ассемблере. Посему я это определение оставляю в уголке памяти и в контексте ООП не использую.

Comment: Ну, да, согласен. Большинство пользователей думает то, что объекты - это экземпляры пользовательских типов (классы и структуры). При этом забывают про такой тип как union (объединение). А в Delphi вообще есть ключевое слово object (аналог class из C) vs record (Сишная структура).

Comment: Пожалуйста, употребляйте термин объект только в смысле ООП. А то путаница ужасная.

Comment: Ну, все так думают ввиду того, что практически во всех учебниках (по крайней мере каких я видел), где учат ООП-подходу, объектами называют экземпляры классов и структур (надо же, я только что узнал, что struct и union тоже классы в С++). Но всё же, в стандарте различаются "object" (An object is a region of storage) и "object of class" (тот же самый объект, но уже в применении только класса). И ввиду избежания путаницы первое понятие лучше не вспоминать без важной на то причины. Стандарт очень мало кто читает (как и я лишь изредка заглядываю) и этого определения даже не знают - не поймут-с.

Comment: В результате имеем - <a href=http://hashcode.ru/questions/2723/%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0>такое</a>
Явно всегда лучше пользоваться англоязычными терминами, чем неточными русскоязычными эквивалентами.

Comment: Ну не всегда, но иногда стоит =)
Терминология, так или иначе, уже сложилась и достаточно устойчивая. Правда не всегда имеющая однозначные аналоги слов на английском, что печально. Если использовать слова в соответствии с ней - Вас, скорее всего, поймут. Если же произносимое слово имеет отличный от принятого смысл - лучше его пояснить или использовать иное слово...

Comment: Я вот не совсем понимаю, как можно называть объектом такую сущность, тип который фактически классом не является, не знает ничего ни про наследование, ни про инкапсуляцию, ни про полиморфизм.

Мы про ООП вообще говорим? Вы всё-таки настаиваете, что переменная типа long int - это именно объект?

Comment: Лично я пришёл к такому выводу: с точки зрения стандарта С++ - это объект (подходит под определение). С точки зрения ООП - нет.

Answer (score 5):

Тут выше писали про то, что

> В C# любая переменная - объект. Ввиду того, что типы int, string, char и все иные - это, так сказать, синонимы соответствующих классов: System.Int32, System.String, System.Char. В С++ - нет.

Так вот, это неправда. Я думаю, ни для кого не секрет, что в C# можно вполне сносно работать с указателями. И указатели при этом объектами не являются.

Comment: Хм, не знал - про то, что указатели не объекты. Хорошо, практически любой тип, роме указателе

Comment: Кстати, тип указателя есть и в виде класса - тот же System.IntPtr. Хотя да, они разные .-.

Answer (score 5):

Объект - это такой тип данных, у которого имеются такие элементы, как поля данных и методы, и который характеризуется свойствами: инкапсуляция и наследование. Обычные переменные этими свойствами обладают? Если обладают, то ДА, это объекты. Если нет, то нет. Кроме того, в описании некоторых языков четко прописано, что переменные обычных типов объектами не являются. Пример - Java.

Comment: > Объект - это такой тип данных, у которого имеются такие элементы, как поля данных и методы, и который характеризуется свойствами: инкапсуляция и наследование.

В языке программирования [Io](http://iolanguage.com/) вообще нет понятия наследования, и тем не менее это ОО язык с объектами.

Answer (score 4):

[Объе́ктно-ориенти́рованное](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5), или объектное, программи́рование (в дальнейшем ООП) — [парадигма программирования](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F), в которой основными концепциями являются понятия объектов и классов. В случае языков с прототипированием вместо классов используются объекты-прототипы.

[Паради́гма программи́рования](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) — это совокупность идей и понятий, определяющих стиль написания программ.

[Объект](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)) — некоторая сущность в виртуальном пространстве, обладающая определённым состоянием и поведением, имеет заданные значения свойств (атрибутов) и операций над ними (методов)[1]. Как правило, при рассмотрении объектов выделяется то, что объекты принадлежат одному или нескольким классам, которые в свою очередь определяют поведение (являются моделью) объекта.

[Переме́нная](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)) в императивном программировании — поименованная, либо адресуемая иным способом область памяти, адрес которой можно использовать для осуществления доступа к данным.

Мой ответ "Переменная, даже в языке поддерживающем ООП, может не быть объектом. Чаще всего (НЕ ВСЕГДА!) переменные типа int, float, char это базовые типы, которые не являются объектами."

Comment: это копипаст с вики?

Comment: Не, последний абзац от себя.

Answer (score 1):

Каждый из вас прав, он прав о C++, а вы правы о C#. С++ ведь не полностью ООП-шный язык, поэтому там есть переменные которые по сути не являются объектами. А на C# все типы, даже int, string, bool и тд, наследуются от базового типа Object поэтому переменные этих типов являются обьектами.

Comment: выше уже написали

> В C# есть сущности, не неследуемые от Object. Это указатели, интерфейсы, параметры типов в дженериках.

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите, как вы запутали дело:

В заголовке - вопрос о ООП,а потом:
"Я утверждаю, что переменная - это в корне тоже объект определенного типа в любом объктно-ориентированном языке."

Для начала разберитесь, что ООП (объектно-ориентированное программирование) - это парадигма, а язык - это реализация.

В споре с товарищем вы неправы, так как перепутав две вещи, не смогли задать конкретный вопрос, - запутали отвечающих.

http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Объектно-ориентированное_программирование

Comment: В заголовке вопрос как раз таки о переменной в ООП, а не об ОПП

Answer (score 0):

Выдержка из википедии:

http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Объектно-ориентированное_программирование

Часть языков (иногда называемых «чисто объектными») целиком построена вокруг объектных средств — в них любые данные (возможно, за небольшим числом исключений в виде встроенных скалярных типов данных) являются объектами, любой код — методом какого-либо класса, и невозможно написать программу, в которой не использовались бы объекты. Примеры подобных языков — Smalltalk, Python, Java, C#, Ruby, AS3. Другие языки (иногда используется термин «гибридные») включают ООП-подсистему в исходно процедурный язык. В них существует возможность программировать, не обращаясь к объектным средствам. Классические примеры — C++, Delphi и Perl.