# Python Сами типы являются объектами, как это понять?

Tags: python, объекты, типы

Цитата: "В действительности в Python даже сами типы представляют собой объекты"
Цитата: "тип объекта является объектом типа type"

Насколько я понимаю: тип - это названия (такие как int, str, list...) объектов которые создает программист, чтобы в целом понимать что это такое и что с этим делать. А объект - это информация которая хранится в памяти (т.е. a = 'abc').

Но моя логика ломается в тот момент, когда я прочитал что тип это объект, как это вообще понимать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это просто означает что типы в python являются, так называемыми, first-class citizens (объекты первого класса). Объекты первого класса - это такие элементы языка, которые можно передавать как параметры в функцию, вернуть в качестве результата выполнения фукнции, или присвоить переменной. Проще говоря, в python можно манипулировать типами точно так же, как и числами, строками или другими объектами.

Возможно, проще будет понять сравнив типы в языке вроде C и в Python. В C типы стираются после компиляции и не существуют во время выполнения программы. В C тип нельзя вернуть из функции в зависмости от входного параметра, нельзя сохранить в переменную и использовать позже, нельзя создать новый тип во время выполнения программы. В Python, с другой стороны, все это возможно:

```py
# Вернуть тип в зависимости от значения параметра
def int_or_float(return_int):
    return int if return_int else float
num_type = int_or_float(False)
# И использовать его
value = num_type('123')

# Динамически создать новый тип
def mk_cls(x):
    class DynamicClass:
        def __init__(self, val):
            self.val = val
        def get(self):
            return self.val + x
    return DynamicClass

# Класс который прибавляет 1
Cls1 = mk_cls(1)
val1 = cls1(10)
assert val1.get() == 11

# Класс который прибавляет 2
Cls2 = mk_cls(2)
val2 = cls2(10)
assert val2.get() == 12
```

Answer (score -1):

Переменная это тоже то, что хранится в памяти

Когда мы работаем с языком, например `C`, типом переменной мы указываем компилятору, какой объём памяти нужно зарезервировать под эту переменную.

Компилятор выделяет место в памяти, и записывает туда это значение

```
short age = 30; // компилятор зарезервировал 2 байта в памяти под эту переменную
int balance = 5000; // 2 или 4 байта под эту
char balanceCurrency = '$'; // 1 байт под эту
```

Здесь о типах и их размерах в памяти языка `C` https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_data_types.htm

---

Дальше по поводу `примитивный тип` это тоже `объект`
Приведу пример на `JavaScript`

Допустим у нас есть переменная:

```
const name = 'Alegro'
```

По сути, переменная `name` является примитивной, то есть переменная `name` является строкой

Но и так же является объектом, у которого со своими методами

Например мы можем сделать так:

```
const nameUpper = name.toUpperCase() // ALEGRO
```

В переменную `nameUpper` мы записали значение, которое вернул встроенный метод переменной `name`

Кстати, почитайте здесь
[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/8337/Является-ли-переменная-объектом-в-ООП](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/8337/%D0%AF%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B2-%D0%9E%D0%9E%D0%9F)

Comment: Есть очень крутой курс на youtube по основам программирования. 
Рекомендую посмотреть 
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLawfWYMUziZqyUL5QDLVbe3j5BKWj42E5

Comment: Полагаю, вопрос не в том как "примитивный тип это тоже объект", а в том, каким образом в ЯП Python "тип переменной является объектом"

Comment: Я за переменную ни слова не говорил, Я сейчас читаю Лутца, и как было сказано в вопросе, не смог понять такие определения как "всё в Python является типом объекта" , "типы объектов по факту тоже являются объектами типов"

Answer (score -1):

Тут все зависит от вашей точки зрения. Например, если рассматривать программу как объект ("который храниться в памяти"), то у неё есть тип .py, .c и т. д.. Но, если рассматривать python, как язык программирования, то это тоже объект, так как его исходники можно посмотреть на githab и у него тоже есть тип - интерпретируемый. В программировании вы все время находитесь на каком-то уровне абстракции, или погружаясь вниз, до машинных команд, не дай бог, то подымаясь вверх, до фреймворков.